# Caching tensorflow dataset before iteration results in empty dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, caching, dataset

I'm using the `from_generator` Method of the Dataset API in TensorFlow.
However, when I iterate through the dataset (to count the samples) with caching enabled, the dataset is empty:

```py
output_signature = (tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(64, 64, 2), dtype=tensorflow.float32),
                        tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tensorflow.int16))
dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator(MSUMFSDFrameGenerator(pathlib.Path(dataset_locations["mfsd"]), True), output_signature=output_signature)
dataset = dataset.repeat().prefetch(buffer_size=tensorflow.data.AUTOTUNE).cache(filename)
size = dataset.reduce(0, lambda x,_: x+1).numpy()
```

But when I cache the dataset **after** iteration, the dataset seems to be fine (but isn't cached then and needs regeneration for training again):

```py
output_signature = (tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(64, 64, 2), dtype=tensorflow.float32),
                        tensorflow.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tensorflow.int16))
dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_generator(MSUMFSDFrameGenerator(pathlib.Path(dataset_locations["mfsd"]), True), output_signature=output_signature)
dataset = dataset.repeat().prefetch(buffer_size=tensorflow.data.AUTOTUNE)
size = dataset.reduce(0, lambda x,_: x+1).numpy()
dataset = dataset.cache(filename)
```

Do you know how to iterate a cached dataset (to obtain the number of samples)?

Comment: Iam surprised that `dataset.repeat()` before the other operations is not running into infinite loop, and will not return a sum in both cases? Don't think `dataset.repeat()` should be there.

Comment: I started without the repeat call and I swear, it didn't work... However, now it's working! Thank you very much.